# Read Wall of a Facebook Page by using the Graph API - possible?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I know we can see the USER WALL by retrieving a token and all... no problem.

However, I have this case in hands, that the request is to display the WALL of a facebook PAGE of a given user.

Does anyone knows if this can be done by using the Graph API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now for FACEBOOK PAGE, it is just the same graphAPI call as for friends wall...just replace the User id to page id, as in the following url

https://graph.facebook.com/40796308305/feed?access_token=2227470867|2.oYiXeutFctg5rAweCFSIPw__.3600.129027.....................

Thats it as simple as that.

Thank you
D

Comment: And where do we get the page ID ? From the URL of that page? Thanks again. I mean, I know we use the application id, the secret id and the token. I don't see where do we use the userId for retrieving the information...

Comment: FOUND: Since this is a public wall it was as simple as:https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE_ID/feed :) Nice. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Hi , do you know how can I find the page id created by user after Oauth?

Comment: btw , this is a very nice facebook graph console i find , you guys might like it http://app.apigee.com/console/facebook