# Read Users Wall using Facebook Graph API for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I want to retrieve all the feeds in the users wall

Posts by my friends,  Posts from the Page I Liked,  Pictures, Videos Posted

basically everything my wall shows.

I used this

```
[facebookObj requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andDelegate:delegateObj];
```

But this results me showing the posts only by me. I cant able to get the feeds by others.

How to get all those feeds.

I have set the permission as read_stream. Do i have to set anymore permissions to get those feeds

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230731/read-wall-of-a-facebook-page-by-using-the-graph-api-possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [/me/home](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/home) instead.

Comment: Do you know how to search some feeds in the wall. I mean i want to extract the feeds by my friends in the wall.

Comment: Can you provide the code how to access(not the permission, after gettingpermissionand displaying it or something like that) friendlist or feed. I am new o this I accesed my name and profile pic but dont know how to get the friend list. I got some code from web using NSDictionary but not completed one. you can answer my question here:[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677434/how-to-access-my-movies-in-ios-through-graph-api[link]